# Reference for the history of the English alphabet

Tags: discussion, reference

I am looking for a text or book that discusses the history of the English alphabet, as in, how the shapes of the alphabet came to be, why certain sounds are associated with certain letters, and how the ordering of the alphabet came to be, and other topics. If this is not the right stack exchange for this question, then it should be migrated to another stack exchange.

Comment: Most of it we stole directly from Latin.

Comment: Probly the best single source is the section in David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_. He provides full information on each letter, in turn, along with **lots** of other information, not restricted to the alphabet. It's a book that should be in every Anglophone classroom in the world, imo.

Comment: ... this kind of question is more for Meta.ELU.SE – Mitch ... and Crystal's _The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_ and _The Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language_ are listed among the reference works.

Comment: I have seen their history in David Crystals Spell it out

Comment: Wikipedia is always a good start: [History of the Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet). Lots of colorful diagrams too.

Comment: [chart of the evolution](https://usefulcharts.com/blogs/charts/evolution-of-the-english-alphabet), also lots of picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=history+of+the+alphabet) if you look at 'Images'